# Trace enabled on varnish servers

Tags: varnish

A scan revealed that trace is enabled on some of my varnish servers. But I thought that trace was only disabled on apache servers. How can this be disabled in varnish?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in order to return `405 - Method not allowed` when varnish receives `TRACE` or `TRACK`:

```
...
sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  if (req.method == "TRACE" || req.method == "TRACK") {
    return (synth(405));
  }
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Where would I add that? I apologize I’m new to Varnish.

Comment: @Nobody, you need to modify the varnish configuration file, i think it will be under `/etc/varnish` directory then look for the `vcl_recv` section and add the `if` condition inside it and make sure there is no other configuration related to `TRACE` or `TRACK` exist already